# What could be different ways of creating a user interface for a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to learn what could be the best ways of developing user interface for chrome extension for my application. The 2 approaches that I have come across are i)Using a browser action with default_popup html page or ii) Injecting some component into the page that is loaded in the tab. First approach is pretty straightforward but has some restricted use (like it is destroyed on tab/window switch which is useful in the context of my application). Coming to the second approach, it seems it requires every component which can be injected to be listed under web_accessible_resources. As the extension UI gets complex, this list is bound to increase. But surprisingly, Pocket extension's manifest does not seem to list any js files or html files though it does not use a popup page too. How does it work? Is there any other way of creating the user interface too?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked on the documentation regarding chrome.windows API? This API will allow you to create new windows and tabs in the browser, so you can create the html content from your extension. All you'll need is declaring the pertinent permissions on the manifest file. You can read more information here:  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows